# Get index on row deleting (devexpress ASPxGridView )

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Today I try to get the current index when clicking on a `CommandColumnCustomButton` button delete. I have a GridView populated with some values at runtime, and here is how I do to add "delete" button for each row of this control :

```
GridViewCommandColumn cmdCol = new GridViewCommandColumn();
cmdCol.Caption = "Edition";
GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton cDelBtn = new GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton();

cDelBtn.ID = "supprimer";
cDelBtn.Text = "supprimer";

cDelBtn.Visibility = GridViewCustomButtonVisibility.AllDataRows;           

cmdCol.CustomButtons.Add(cDelBtn);
gridView_test.Columns.Add(cmdCol);
```

It simply create a column with at each row a button which allows to delete the row.

Right after the last line of the code above, I added a line which precise to do something at click on those "delete" button. Here is the code to do so :

```
gridView_test.ClientSideEvents.CustomButtonClick = "function (s, e) { alert( e.FocusedRowIndex ); }";
```

The function takes two argument (like the event handler basic function in ASP) : s is the "sender", which represent the object (there, it is the "delete" button), and e is the "event". I tried so to catch the current index of the event but it doesn't works, displaying me "undefined".

Please see below an example of the working process I would like to implement :

```
PRICE  |   Edit
  5    |  delete
  18   |  delete
```

I would like, when clicking on the "delete" button from the second line, to display "1", which is the index of the array which represent the GridView (because as you know arrays begin from index 0...).

Some knows how can I could do this in the javascript part of my function right below ? Or maybe an alternative exists ?

***Further Informations :
DevExpress version : 14.1
Control : ASPxGridView
IDE : Visual Studio 2013
Langage : ASP.net WebForms***

Comment: Instead of `alert(e.FocusedRowIndex)`, use `console.log(e)`  and see the object structure of `e` and use write property.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error, it was not the proper proprety I used. Better use "visibleIndex" attribute :

```
e.visibleIndex
```